# What is the best mapping software to use for mobile navigation devices?

Tags: mapping, navigation, gps

I'm starting to work on a project that involves integration with the mapping software on a navigation device.  Ideally the navigation device will be touch screen, and we will be able to write code that controls the navigation/mapping software on the device (we want to send info to and from the mobile device -it will be in a car permanently).

What mapping software and mobile platform would you recommend for such a job?

Comment: Team Phoenix, working on taxibuses by any chance?

Comment: That's right lol - we're using Geobase at the moment, but we wanted to see what other people are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise TomTom. *Disclaimer: they pay me.*

It's a cheap device, and runs Linux. We've recently introduced the TomTom Blue&Me for Fiat. The "blue" part refers to the fact that it talks with the car using Bluetooth, e.g. the TomTom will find a pump when the car tells the TomTom it's running low on gas. Your project sounds similar enough.

Comment: What we'd want to do is to put a gui on top of the mapping software, to add our own functionality.  Is this possible to do with TomTom? I haven't seen any developer APIs or anything like that

Comment: That suddenly sounds a lot harder, to the point where you'd need signed NDAs. As long as you stay off the device, there's the "Add to TomTom"  interface used by e.g. Google Maps. If you're willing and able to replace the navigation software and maps, it's a cheap device with a up-and-running Linux stack. But the on-device API hasn't been maintained (it doesn't sell devices, basically).